# Get x,y from Top, Left, Width and Height for Corona Objects

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Good day

I just started using Corona and I'm kinda confused with this x and y properties. Is it possible to perhaps get the x and y values using Top, Left, Width and Height properties if these are provided? For example, I want an an object to be at `Left=10`, `Top=0`, `Width=40` and `Height=40`. Can someone please advise how I can do this, this could be for images, text, textfield etc

Answer (score 1):

Of course. There are several methods to do this.

**Example 1:**

```
local myImage = display.newImageRect( "homeBg.png", 40, 40)
myImage.anchorX = 0; myImage.anchorY = 0 
myImage.x = 10 -- Left gap 
myImage.y = 0  -- Top gap
localGroup:insert(myImage)
```

Here, setting the anchor points to (0,0) will make the reference point of your images' geometric center to its top left corner.

**Example 2:**

```
local myImage = display.newImageRect( "homeBg.png", 40, 40)
myImage.x = (myImage.contentWidth/2) + 10
myImage.y = (myImage.contentHeight/2)
localGroup:insert(myImage)
```

Here, the center-X position of your image is calculated by adding `Left gap` to the `image's half width` itself. And the center-Y position is calculated by adding `Top gap` to the `image's half height`

You can position the objects with any of such methods. If you are a beginner in corona, then the following topics will be useful for you to get more knowledge about Displaying Objects with specific size, position, etc.

- [Corona SDK : display.newImageRect()](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/newImageRect.html)
- [Tutorial: Anchor Points in Graphics 2.0](https://coronalabs.com/blog/2013/10/15/tutorial-anchor-points-in-graphics-2-0/)

Comment: Perfect, thanks it works! I have upvoted the response.

Answer (score 0):

Corona uses like a *Cartesian Coordinate System* **But** the (0,0) is on the **TOP LEFT** you can view more here:

https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/graphics/group.html#coordinates

BUT:  You can get the screen corners based on the image width and height using this codes:

***NOTE THAT YOU SHOULD YOU SHOULD CHANGE IT WITH YOUR IMAGE***

```
local image = display.newImageRect(“images/yourImage.png”, width, height)

--TOP: 

image.y = math.floor(display.screenOriginY + image*0.5)

--BOTTOM:

image.y = math.floor(screenH - display.screenOriginY) - image.height*.5 

--LEFT: 

image.x = (screenOffsetW*.5) + image*.5

--RIGHT: 

image.x = math.floor(screenW - screenOffsetW*.5) - image.width*.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Corona SDK display objects have attributes that can be read or set:

X = myObject.x  -- gets the current center (by default) of myObject
width = myObject.width

You can set these values too....

myObject.x = 100 -- centers the object at 100px left of the content area.

By default Corona SDK's are based on their center, unless you change it's anchor point:

```
myObject.anchorX = 0
myObject.anchorY = 0

myObject.x = 100
myObject.y = 100
```

by setting the anchor's to 0, then .x and .y refer to the top left of the object.